# When was a partition of unity discovered?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, differential-geometry

A [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) is a mathematical concept in geometry. I want to know when and in what context this concept appeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partitions of unity were formally introduced by Dieudonne (C. R. 205 (1937) 593-595), and for some time they were even called "Dieudonne decompositions".
However is some special cases they were used by Whitney (TAMS, 36 (1934) 63-89).
This information is taken from Hormander, Analysis of Partial differential operators, vol. I, comments to Chapter I.

Comment: I don't know if it is the same concept that Dieudonne used, but the term "Zerlegung der Einheit" appeared already in John von Neumann's 1929 paper on Hermitian operators in a Hilbert space: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002273535&physid=PHYS_0064

Comment: I suppose this is a different partition of different "unity" which von Neuman used: a representation of the unity operator as a sum of projectors. Dieudonne (and I) meant a representation of the functon "one" as a sum of functions with compact support.

Comment: Yes, what von Neumann did is today called [resolution of the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Resolution_of_the_identity)